# Is there an argument against using a CMS?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, workflow

I'm thinking about rebuilding my website from scratch, but this time, using a CMS. Everywhere I turn people tell me to use a cms, but it's only now I'm really considering it. My site isn't too complicated. Is this a good idea in terms of workflow? I'm the only person who will edit the site, so if it's just a matter of workflow and efficiency, should I just convert now before it gets really big?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, a few come to mind.

Deployment complexity. Many CMSes require a database, which means running a database process somewhere, and backing that up, as well as the rest of the code and assets for the site.

More space will be required to hold the CMS code for the manager, framework, libraries, etc.

Bloat could come into play, the CMS may, and likely would, implement features you have no use for.

Additionally any CMS will have some kind of limitations, some things will be more tricky to do than others when compared to a mostly static site.

Comment: But would you say that it is much faster and easier to just put up something with a CMS?

Comment: Definitely. Your question asked for the arguments against, however I think the pros of using a CMS (especially a good one) outweigh the cons. The ability to edit the site from anywhere, from any computer, for example is a big one for me. Ease of uploading new material, images, etc. Availability of plugins to add features that you don't have to develop on your own. The list goes on.

Comment: I would add to your list - opportunity cost. The time, effort, and cost of going this route could be used for something else. Is the something else likely to be more interesting/efficient/provide a greater return on your investment.

Answer (score 1):

Just read the code. That's often all the arguments you need. (If your needs are really simple and you don't need plugins and you don't need to write any code yourself I'd still use a CMS, though)

Answer (score 1):

If your site is mainly a design showcase, and doesn't have real content in it, then a CMS will only get in your way and make things harder.

Otherwise, it will mostly be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Along with everyone else's statements. If it's just a small site you don't necessarily need a CMS, but if you are wanting to use a CMS for client projects in the future, why not start now.

Answer (score 0):

Deployment. If you're doing some big changes to your site or testing something, you'll probably want to try it out locally with a development copy of the database. Once you're done, how do you get everything to the live site without overwriting, say, comments that were made on the live site since you created a development copy?

Specialization. CMS's are great for some things, but they're bad at others. What if you want to add more complex functionality to your site? It might be a plugin or module at first, but soon you're writing all this code and you realize you should have just used a framework and built the CMS part yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a simple static site with a single editor and without any aspirations of using complicated functionality and you feel confident enough in your web language of choice, then go for it. Even if you don't feel confident enough, it should be a good challenge.

Write some minor templating so that you can separate your code from your design, have some simple way of adding articles or blog posts or whatever - it could be as simple as including text files from a directory.

Using a CMS, even in their modern and quite usable state will require more resources, hardware-wise. and will probably have a steep learning curve. It will also require maintenance and dilligent security patch application as new vulnerabilities appear. On the other hand a CMS can get you up and running with a basic site quickly, and grow with your needs if you feel like enriching it, as you get to use its large variety of ready made plugins and extensions. You want blog comments with users logging in via OAuth? No problem. RSS? There's an extension for that.

Bottom line is, if this is a simple static site with a single editor as you describe it, it should be trivial to set up some code to run it. You'll spend as much time on its template design as you would on customizing a CMS's template, avoid the initial learning curve a CMS requires, and not worry too much about the resources and maintenance a modern CMS requires. You will, however, be limited in functionality and future ideas by what you can write or integrate yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It depends somewhat on the purpose of the site.

If it is a means to an end of getting information posted on the web, then adopting something like WordPress will quickly get you going, and provide lots of extra functionality that would take a fair amount of time to build in - e.g. stats, feeds, remote publishing etc.  There are a few basic steps you'll need to go through setting up self-hosting on a shared web-hosting package e.g. creating the DB and unzipping the files etc but fairly straightforward really.  And the time you save administering your website can be focussed on other things where you're making a difference or doing something different to everyone else.

However if your purpose is in part the learning experience of developing the functionality or you have unusual requirements that aren't in a standard CMS, then there is an argument for developing your own.